# Compare two arrayList get common value and it should it not affect original values

Tags: java

```
public void commonId(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdList) {
    if (stylistIdList.size() > 1) {
        array1=stylistIdList.get(0);
        array2=stylistIdList.get(1);
        booleanStylistid=array1.retainAll(array2);
    } else {
        array1=stylistIdList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Here I am having `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdList` contains two `arraylist` i want get common values from the two list.Its returning the common values but after getting common values the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdList` value is changed into the values which is common.I want same values in `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdList` after getting common values.

Example

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdLis = 0(0["abcdefgh"], ["abc"]), 1(0["abcdefgh"]);
```

output `stylistIdList=("abcdefgh");`

after getting output the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdLis` values is changed into `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdLis = 0("abcdefgh"), 1("abcdefgh");`
But it i want like this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stylistIdLis = 0(0["abcdefgh"],["abc"]), 1(0["abcdefgh"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`retainAll` modifies the list it is called on. If you want to get the common IDs without modifying the original lists, you need to return a new list.

```
public ArrayList<String> commonIds(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists) {
    List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(lists.get(0));
    if (lists.size() > 1) common.retainAll(lists.get(1));

    return common;
}
```

Comment: K i will try this